# jQuery- vertical div scroll with buttons won't scroll continuously

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, bind, smoothing

so I have a div that looks like `<div id="scroller">...</div>` and inside this div is a bunch of content and the overflow is set to hidden.

I am attempt to make a smooth scrolling vertical div. I have a button on top of the div `id='up'` and a button on the bottom `id='down'`.

Right now when I click the up or down buttons the div will scroll, but only about 1 or 2 lines  (each click).

Can someone please explain to me how I would bind this function so it continuously scrolls while the mouse is pressed down? Also, it feels more like a click up/down rather than a smooth scroll.

Is there a different function I should use rather than scrollTop()?

Heres a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TPKDG/1/)

Any help with this would be great!
Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeoutId = 0;

function scrollIt(amount){
    $('#scroller').scrollTop($('#scroller').scrollTop()+amount);
}

$('#down').mousedown(function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(scrollIt(5), 1000);
}).bind('mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});

$('#up').mousedown(function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(scrollIt(-5), 1000);
}).bind('mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
});
```

**WORKING SOLUTION**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeoutId = 0;

    function scrollIt(amount){
$('#scroller').scrollTop($('#scroller').scrollTop()+amount);
}

$('#down').mousedown(function() {
    timeoutId = setInterval(function(){scrollIt(5)}, 20);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearInterval(timeoutId);
});

$('#up').mousedown(function() {
    timeoutId = setInterval(function(){scrollIt(-5)}, 20);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearInterval(timeoutId);
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="scrollup" id="up">&nbsp;</div> 

 <div id="scroller" class="scroller buttongroup">  
    blah blah
    content blah
    blah blah
    content blah
</div>

<div class="scrolldown" id="down">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. the onmousedown event is only fired once, not repeatedly, so a single call to `setTimeout` will only happen once. The solution is to use `setInterval` (and `clearInterval` respectively) to have the method be repeatedly called until the interval is cleared
2. The first parameter to `setTimeout`/`setInterval` must be a function. You're actually passing the return value of `scrollIt(5)` which is `undefined`. You have to pass the actual function itself, i.e. just `scrollIt`. That of course leaves you with the problem of not being able to tell it whether to add 5 or subtract 5. You can solve that by simply wrapping the call in anonymous function and passing that:

   ```
   setInterval(function(){ scrollIt(5) }, 1000)
   ```

Also, 1000 milliseconds is a *very* slow interval for something like scrolling. You need to knock that down to about 250. Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sWjU/1/) with all these changes in effect.

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly where my error was. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I removed the , 1000 and switch the ammount `scrollIt(5)` to scrollIt(1) and got the speed I was looking for. Thank you for your update.